# Unable to run PHP unit

Tags: php, phpunit

I followed the below tutorial step by step to run PHPUnit. But I am only getting options and configuration part.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRVkchE5kuE&t=393s

Followed the below steps to setup PHPUnit:-

1. Installed the composer.
2. Installed the PHPUnit via command line
   PHP composer.phar require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^8

After these steps, I am able to get the version, options, configuration, and other information by using the command

PHPUnit (on path cd /vendor/bin/)

In the tutorial below steps used to run the PHPUnit:-

1. create phpunit.xml file on root and defined the below code.

   ```
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
       <phpunit bootstrap = "vendor/autoload.php">
           <testsuits>
               <testsuit name = "unit">
                   <directory>tests</directory>
               </testsuit>
           </testsuits>
       </phpunit>
   ```
2. Created the tests directory on the root and also create unit directory in the tests directory and again run the below command.

phpunit on path cd /vendor/bin/

But still, I am getting information part. but in the video, he is getting tested ok line after the command.

Please suggest me, what am I doing wrong?

This is the file structure

> `R:
>         vendor
>            bin
>            composer
>            doctrine
>           .
>           .
>           .
>           .
>           .
>           .
>            autoload.php
>        tests
>            unit
>        composer.json
>        composer.lock
>        composer.phar
>        phpunit.xml`

Comment: can you provide your folder structure

Comment: Can you provide the result of phpunit command ?

Comment: I edited my question and defined file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run `phpunit` from the `/vendor/bin/` directory, run it from your project's root directory (the same place as the `phpunit.xml` file):

`/project/dir # vendor/bin/phpunit`

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am getting error 

"phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I also defined my file structure, I hope it will help you.

Comment: but when I am executing the below command

R:\vendor\bin>phpunit

I am getting this

PHPUnit 8.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Usage:
  phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
  phpunit [options] <directory>

Code Coverage Options:

  --coverage-clover <file>    Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format

  --coverage-crap4j <file>    Generate code coverage report in Crap4J XML format

Comment: but you said run from root directory

Comment: according to my file structure, please can you tell me the exact command

Comment: @akshaygoyal:   from the directory "R:\", run the command "vendor\bin\phpunit"